# Get the information from one column into another SQL

Tags: sql, database

can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I have two tables I have to fetch all customers who have an unexpired transaction. However, this condition must be true for both tables. For this reason I made a join between the two tables to verify that both dates are not expired,if both exist otherwise if the second is null only the first.Finally I should merge the information I have horizontally into a single column.
For example in this case i have this result for the join:

[image]

I would like to union the information of the last three columns in the first three so as to have a single block.
id_client,id_tran,expiry with id_client 1,2,3,5,6 all togheter.

```
 create table tab1 (
id_client int,
id_trans int,
expiry date)

create table tab2 (
id_client int,
id_trans int,
expiry date)

insert into tab1 values (1,101,'02-03-2020')
insert into tab1 values (1,102,'22-07-2022')
insert into tab1 values (2,201,'23-05-2023')
insert into tab1 values (3,301,'02-03-2022')
insert into tab1 values (3,302,'12-10-2024')

insert into tab2 values (4,101,'12-03-2023')
insert into tab2 values (5,102,'21-08-2024')
insert into tab2 values (6,201,'21-08-2024')


SELECT * from tab1 a
left join tab2 b
on a.id_trans = b.id_trans
where a.expiry > getdate()
AND coalesce(B.expiry,'2900-12-31') > getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 queries, one of which will return all records when a client has more than 1 unexpired transaction per table, and the other which uses `max` to return the latest one. (We could equally user `min` to get the oldest one or `string_agg` to list them all.)

> ```
> with clients as
> (select id_client from tab1
> union select id_client from tab2)
> select 
>   c.id_client,
>   t1.id_trans t1,
>   t1.expiry t1_expiry,
>   t2.id_trans t2,
>   t2.expiry t2_expiry
> from clients c
> left join tab1 t1
> on c.id_client = t1.id_client
> left join tab2 t2
> on c.id_client = t2.id_client
> where coalesce(t1.expiry,'2900-12-31') > getdate()
> and coalesce(t2.expiry,'2900-12-31') > getdate()
> order by c.id_client;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id_client |   t1 | t1_expiry  |   t2 | t2_expiry 
> --------: | ---: | :--------- | ---: | :---------
>         1 |  102 | 2022-07-22 |  101 | 2022-09-12
>         2 |  201 | 2023-05-23 | null | null      
>         3 |  302 | 2024-10-12 | null | null      
>         4 | null | null       |  101 | 2023-03-12
>         5 | null | null       |  102 | 2024-08-21
>         6 | null | null       |  201 | 2024-08-21
>         6 | null | null       |  101 | 2022-09-12
> ```

> ```
> with clients as
> (select id_client from tab1
> union select id_client from tab2)
> select 
>   c.id_client,
>   max(t1.id_trans) t1,
>   max(t1.expiry) t1_expiry,
>   max(t2.id_trans) t2,
>   max(t2.expiry) t2_expiry
> from clients c
> left join tab1 t1
> on c.id_client = t1.id_client
> left join tab2 t2
> on c.id_client = t2.id_client
> where coalesce(t1.expiry,'2900-12-31') > getdate()
> and coalesce(t2.expiry,'2900-12-31') > getdate()
> group by c.id_client
> order by c.id_client;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id_client |   t1 | t1_expiry  |   t2 | t2_expiry 
> --------: | ---: | :--------- | ---: | :---------
>         1 |  102 | 2022-07-22 |  101 | 2022-09-12
>         2 |  201 | 2023-05-23 | null | null      
>         3 |  302 | 2024-10-12 | null | null      
>         4 | null | null       |  101 | 2023-03-12
>         5 | null | null       |  102 | 2024-08-21
>         6 | null | null       |  201 | 2024-08-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=26347186712465da4d2a9421d5425ada)*

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply and your interest in the post. I really like the intuition of the cte.
However, record 4 should not come out because it does not respect the condition that both dates must not have expired and in the case of transaction 4 the first date has expired so it should not be taken into consideration.
1 if both dates exist, not the first and second must not be expired
2 if only the first exists, it must not be expired
Maybe the join should be done on the trans id and not on the client